# npm or java script issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

Hey guys is this a javascript issue or an npm issue? If there is something wrong with my JS code can someone please tell me whats wrong with it?

**NOTE**
    I borrowed some code for getting the current uid from firebase.. I am no JS programmer

entire code file:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var uid = event.params.uid;
exports.announceProduct = functions.database
 .ref('users/{uid}/notifications')
.onCreate(event => {
   let note = event.data.val();
  sendNotification(note);
  });

function sendNotification(note) {
 let title = note.title;
 let action = note.action;
 let user = note.user;

 let payload = {
notification: {
  title: 'user',
  body: 'action',
  sound: 'default'
}
 };
}
```

console error

[error with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkUyP.png)

Thank you!!

Comment: indenting your code will go a long way in helping you identify typos

Comment: Flagged for closure because *typo error*

Answer (score 1):

There are no closing braces for several opening braces. add three `}`'s to the end of this code. There are missing commas for the `payload` object properties. You are missing an arrow for event in the onCreate method. Methods can accept functions as parameters but you were trying a declaration as a function parameter which is not permitted.

EDIT:
try this code:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var uid = event.params.uid;
exports.announceProduct = functions.database
  .ref('users/{uid}/notifications')
  .onCreate(event => {
    let note = event.data.val();
    sendNotification(note);
  });

function sendNotification(note) {
  let title = note.title;
  let action = note.action;
  let user = note.user;

  let payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'user',
      body: 'action',
      sound: 'default'
    }
  };
}
```

EDIT: to help answer your edited question. You are using a variable called `event` in `var uid = event.params.uid` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: after a fresh deploy still got the same error... I think its the code where I get the current user id from firebase thats causing trouble it doesn't look correct to me.. would you happen to know how to fix the code above? thanks

Comment: see my edit  @Zachscs  the purpose is for setting up notification service for push notifications on google firebase

Comment: There were several issues, compare my code to yours, this at least gets rid of syntax errors.

Comment: I put it in... after deploy I got a new error... :( I took a sc for you above thanks alot mate

Comment: Stop changing your question, leave it in original state and add an edit comment

Comment: Im sorry.. I thought I was being helpful ima noob to stackoverflow as you can probably tell

Comment: It just looks like I said try this code and posted the same code in your question... `event` is not defined. I'd move this to chat but you don't have enough rep (20 minimum) to talk in chat.

Comment: I cant chat website wont allow @zachscs

Comment: I thought your code would work... all im trying to do is get the current logged in user id from firebase and I took that snippet off the internet if you know of a right way to do it id love to hear , thanks agian @Zachscs